# Bootstrap Validator after server side

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, validation

I am having a form which I validate client side using bootstrap and validator.
Example:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5">
   <label>EMAIL ADDRESS</label>
   <input class="form-control" id="Email" type="email" name="email" required="" data-error="Email address is required" value="maor@traseatlas.com" placeholder="">
   <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
```

That's working great. what I would like to do next is sending the form to server side and have there another validation.

What I expect to have is when the server side is returning an error code that a field is not validated correctly to have the validator "turned on" via changing the CSS and such, and let it continue with the same behaviour as like it was failed on client side.

So, how can I manipulate the HTML / CSS so that when it's coming back from server I will have the same warnings on screen ?

I am not using Ajax for the server side validation, just a normal post to page.

Thank you.

Comment: Good question! I am also waiting for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to have an $errors array. As you go through your validation, you push any errors into said array. If, at the end, the $errors array contains any errors, you re-display the page, injecting your error messages as appropriate.

A naive example:

```
<?php

    $errors = [];

    if(empty($_POST['some-required-field'])){
        $errors['some-required-field'] = "Some Required Field is required!";
    }

    // ... the rest ...

    if(count($errors) == 0){
        header('Location: /your-success-page.php');
    }
?>
```

Then, in the markup of the form:

```
<?php if(isset($errors['some-required-field'])): ?>
    <p class="help-block with-errors">
        <?: $errors['some-required-field'] ?>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I thought about that, but then the font color is not red, and the border of the field is not red and it's focused on it. I was sure there is something else which can trigger the same validation as like i press submit on form.